# What is the meaning of lbr in Vim?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim, line-breaks

I write `set lbr` in my `vimrc` file but I don't know the meaning of that. What does this option do?
I know it's about line-breaking but I need more explanation.
This is from the Vim document and I can not understand it.

> If on, Vim will wrap long lines at a character in 'breakat' rather
> than at the last character that fits on the screen.

Can someone explain this document to me by an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `lbr` is not set and `wrap` is set the long lines will be break at the window width (cutting words in two if necessary).

If present and `wrap` is set the long line will be break as much as possible at a character that belong to `breakat` (typically after a punctuation or a white space).

If you have 45 positions available on screen.

You have without `lbr` (`:set nolbr` and `set wrap`):
[image]

You have with `lbr` (`:set lbr` and `:set wrap`)
[image]

If `wrap` is not set the line are not wrapped (`:set nowrap`)
[image]